# Ormlite foreign field giving me null on response and sometimes duplicate field

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm having issue on joining tables on ormlite. On the first load i have my pojo ready for insertion of data from api using retrofit and gson as the tools.

Here's my pojos:

```
public class ParticipantDetailsModel {

@DatabaseField(id = true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField
private String first_name;

@DatabaseField
private String last_name;
```

}

```
public class Trainings implements Serializable {

@DatabaseField
private int participant_id;

@DatabaseField
private int batch_id;

@DatabaseField
private int graduation_program_id;

@DatabaseField
private int id;

@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, foreignAutoCreate = true)
private ParticipantDetailsModel participant;
```

}

On that Pojo i am actually getting duplicate field id which is "participant_id". So what i did is to rename this field from private ParticipantDetailsModel participant to private ParticipantDetailsModel participants, just for me to get the data. but once i query im not getting any values:

```
QueryBuilder<Trainings, String> qb1 = dao1.queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<ParticipantDetailsModel, String> qb2 = dao2.queryBuilder();
qb1.where().eq("id", item.getId()).and().in("participant_id", parId);
List<Trainings> u = qb1.join(qb2).query();
```

do you have any idea what im missing?

heres my db:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y6j0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Ormlite documentation

> 2.12 Foreign Object Fields
>
> ...
>
> Notice that the name of the field is not account but is instead account_id. You will
> need to use this field name if you are querying for it. You can set the column name using
> the columnName field in the DatabaseField annotation

To set the columnName use:

```
 public static final String ID_COLUMN = "ID";

 @DatabaseField(columnName = ID_COLUMN)
 private int                id;
```

To make the query work, you have to set a `Where` clause on `qb2` as well.

```
qb1.where().eq("id", item.getId());
qb2.where().in("id", parId);
List<Trainings> u = qb1.join(qb2).query();
```

Comment: its not working, but perhaps, using those two pojos i am having error as duplicate id. @DatabaseField private int participant_id;, is there a way i can make it work?